# Why do I only get integer solutions to my LP?

Tags: c++, integer, boolean, cplex

I have an integer programming model and I want to solve its linear relaxation with CPLEX. Originally, I had defined my variables as:

```
BoolVarMatrix X(env,I);
for(IloInt i = 0; i < I; i++){
  X[i] = IloBoolVarArray(env, J);
}

IloBoolVarArray y(env,J);
```

But now I should relax them to the range of `0<=x<=1`, `0<=Y<=1`. In order to do that I changed the definition to:

```
NumVarMatrix X(env,I, 0, 1);
for(IloInt i = 0; i < I; i++){
  X[i] = IloNumVarArray(env, J, 0, 1);
}

IloNumVarArray y(env,J, 0, 1);
```

But it still gives me an integer solution. What should I have done instead?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible that your relaxed LP also has an optimal solution that are integers. One quick way to verify that is to add **binding cuts** to force it to assume some fractional values.

Modify the lb and ub for X1: Take `0 <= x1 <= 1` and make it (say) `0.01 <= x1 <= 0.99` and now solve the LP. Do this for all the variables that were binary in your original formulation.

In other words, make the **ub** and **lb** of `IloNumVarArray` to be fractional and if you get fractional values in your optimal solution, you know that you have done the relaxation right.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to convert the binary variables to ILOFLOAT. Define a new model instance, like LPRelax, and use IloConversion as below:

```
IloModel LpRelax(env); 
LpRelax.add(model); 
LpRelax.add(IloConversion(env, vars, ILOFLOAT));

IloCplex cplex(env); 
cplex.extract(LpRelax); 
cplex.solve();
```

If you still get integral solution, your problem **might be** integral. I mean your coefficinet has special property, like TOTALY UNIMODULARITY, together with integral RHS produce an integral solution.

Hope it could help :-).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your constraint coefficient matrix A (AX=b) is unimodular.